# Rails simple sql comparison with another attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, where-clause

I think this should be quite simple. I want to do something like:

```
User.where("created_at < ?", :updated_at)
```

updated_at is another attribute of the User

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why was this vote down without explanation?

Comment: What kind of DB are you using? MySQL? PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
john = User.where(username: 'john').first
users_updated_before_john = User.where('created_at < ?', john.updated_at)
```

---

After you commented:

> *I'm trying to do something like `User.where("created_at < ?", Date.today - :updated_at)` And I want the attribute created_at be compared with the updated_at for each user, not with the a static one.*

Here is how you do it: **(PostgreSQL 9.1 syntax!)**

```
User.where('users.created_at::date < (users.updated_at::date - integer '5')')
```

The **documentation about Date/Time functions** in PostgreSQL (9.1):

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: This works for this example, but I wanted to do it more complicated. Actually I'm trying to do something like:
User.where("created_at < ?", Date.today - :updated_at) 
And I want the attribute created_at be compared with the updated_at for each user, not with the a static one.

Comment: but now, how can you manipulate it? how can you do something like user.updated_at - 5.days?